# How to initially filter data on the client with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new with Angular and just recently went through a course on using Angular in your MVC site. I'm now trying to take what was shown in the training and try to implement it in a small site I've done. I've got a requirement that the training doesn't address and I'm not exactly sure how to include in my code.

This is a site for a small company to track customer calls when they leave messages. The records can be in one of many status' like open, closed, in progress, need call back, etc.

When the page starts up, I call a web service that returns all of the records. However, I want it to initially filter by "OPEN" and just show that until another filter is chosen from a dropdownlist. So the default status would be "1" or "OPEN".

What would be a good way to filter the records once the page loads? I'm assuming I would need some kind of property like vm.FilterId which 
I would initially set to "1" and then the dropdownlist would change that value?

How would I go about filtering the data on the client?

Here is my API call in my angualr file called "call.controller.js".

```
function callList(){
    dataService.get("/api/Call")
    .then(function(result) { 
        vm.calls = result.data;
    }, 
    function (error) {
        handleException(error)
    });
}
```

This is my ng-repeat that I put on my  tag inside a table tag. I'm assuming this might be where I would try to do some kind of filtering?

```
<tr ng-repeat="call in vm.calls">
```

**UPDATE**

From what I'm understanding I should be able to do something like this to initially filter? This is returning nothing. The status field is an Integer.

```
<tr ng-repeat="call in vm.calls | filter:{ status: 1}">
```

I can see the values come from the API.
[image]

Comment: documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the ng-repeat directive using the pipe.

option 1:

```
 <div ng-repeat="call in vm.calls | filter:{ open: value}">
```

option 2:

```
Value source: <input type="text" ng-model="search.open">
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:open">
```

You can check for example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be some thing similar but wasn't sure how to implement it. I'll look at option 1 you have and I'm assuming "open" would be a property I would set in my angular file? I would then default that to "1" and tie my dropdownlist to that property as well?

Comment: open, is a property of the objects you get from the service. The filter will do the comparision of the open field of the objects and the value you put it. The value can be a model attribute which can be changed via dropdownlist like you said.

Comment: I added an update to my initial post. Based on your recommendations and what I've researched so far I came up with this but it isn't displaying anything. <tr ng-repeat="call in vm.calls | filter:{ status: 1}">. Do you see anything that would keep that from working?

Comment: The syntax is right, the field selector is case sensitive, in the screenshot the status has Capital letter. Try it filter:{ Status: 1}">

Comment: Thanks. I should have caught the spelling on "Status". At least I go the data to return and show on the page now but it's not filtering using the filter code on my <tr>. It looks like the syntax should be correct but is still displaying all the records. I'll just keep trying some different things. This is what I have now: <tr ng-repeat="call in vm.calls | filter:{ Status: 1}">.